# Regex best practice: multiple patterns or single one with combined expression?

Tags: java, regex, caching

Think of the following scenario:

1. Application receives a list of regex from server (*HTTP GET returns a List with each item indicating a regular expression.*);
2. User input text needs to be validate against these expressions;
3. Application runs on Android, so memory is an issue;
4. List of expressions **is not** frequently changed.

What would be better:

1. Cache several Pattern objects, each one containing a single regex returned from server;
2. Concatenate the regex - `(REGEX1)|(REGEX2)|(REGEX3)...|(REGEXN)` - and maintain a single object on memory? - refreshing it whenever a single regex is added or removed, *which doesn't happens very often*.

Comment: `Application receives a list of regex from server` ... what does this mean?  Can you give us an example of your data pipeline?

Comment: An HTTP GET returns a List<String> with each item indicating a regular expression.

Comment: If user input is short, the method doesn't matter. If user input is long, don't concatenate the patterns (except if each of them is anchored to the start and end of the string). Whatever try to reduce the number of patterns.

Comment: What if input is huge?

Comment: And how many regex do you wanna use? If it's not more than thousands then there is no real benefit of keeping it in one string.

Comment: It would be definitely less than one hundred. I cannot control the complexity of the regex once it is up to the client input them. @Alex Baranowski having them all in one single regex would simplify the cache refresh process perhaps?

Comment: Well I'm not very fluent with regex in Java (I'm mainly python Programmer), but there is serious question. What about parsing regex? Parsing short regex is much less complicated than parsing long one. On the other hand parsing all regex at once can create better state machine. If I could be honest - this question needs serious benchmark :)

Comment: I'm mainly concerned about the number of objects I'll have to keep in memory in case I do not concatenate them in one single expression. Thanks for the contribution Alex

Answer (score 2):

I don't imagine there is a way to answer this question without having a specific list of regex's and the list of input.  Because, each regex/input combination is going to result in a different amount of memory used.  Here is what my instincts tell me:

1. Evaluate the Regex's one at a time.  In the "OR" scenario, the regex must simultaneously evaluate all of the OR'd expressions, so that would take more RAM, I believe.
2. Order the Regex's in order of either: (a) Likelihood to match, so that you can abandon evaluating the rest of the regex's or (b) Early non-matching, so that the regex can be quickly discarded as never going to match (for example "^a" only requires evaluating the first character of the string where as "a" requires searching the whole string for an "a".)

Ultimately, only testing can really tell you what takes more time/memory, I'm afraid.